# Two-sided inequalities in PHP

Tags: php, operators, inequality

In PHP, is there any way to express a two-sided inequality like this:

```
if( 10 <= $your_price < 15 ){echo 'Bingo!';}
```

without having to do

```
if( 10 <= $your_price and $your_price < 15 ){echo 'Bingo!';}
```

You would think that the former is more efficient than the latter as there is some redudancy in having to write `and` and repeat `$your_price`.

Comment: There was a proposal in 2016, but I don't know if it went through... It's marked as inactive so I wouldn't try too hard...

source : https://wiki.php.net/rfc/chaining_comparison

Comment: As a contrived example... What would this syntax do to existing expressions like `if ($a <= $b === false)`?  Sure, the `=== false` part is superfluous and it could be written better.  But it works and does what it's expected to do.  This proposed change would break that previously working code.

Comment: @David Python made it work (somewhat), though. You can chain comparisons in that language, but what is stupid is that you can make chains that are unreadable :
`1 < 3 > 2 == 2 < 5` works, even though it maybe shouldn't....